# Trying to find book or series which includes an alien transportation system humans don't control but use

Tags: story-identification, novel

Remember reading this many years ago.  One of the features of it was an alien transportation system where you would go to a certain place and would be protected by a forcefield and the transportation mechanism would pick you up and transport you (like teleporting) to another place (which could be another world entirely) after some time.  Humans used it but it was of alien origin and so they couldn't control it very well - they would have to wait for the beam to sweep to them and grab them and hypothesised that if they could control it fully they would be able to transport on command.  In some cases the sweep took years to get to people, but they were held in a type of impervious stasis so they didn't die and couldn't be killed during this time but it was a risk especially in outlying systems.

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: What years would "many years ago" be?

Comment: I mean would have to be 15+ years ago, most likely 20+ I would say.

Comment: So you read it in 2000 or earlier, but was it published around that time or was it possibly from way earlier? Was it written in English, was it a translation? Any recollection of the cover?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the answers to those Jenayah, but I suspect English original.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in Space, by C. C. MacApp
[https://www.amazon.com/Somewhere-Space-Other-Stories-MacApp/dp/1605437239/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1605437239)

Some time before this story begins, people found alien teleportation technology on Mars. Since then, it’s been used routinely, with few problems. Up until now, that is. Without explanation, folks without close relatives or friends disappear into thin air after using the teleportation device. The protagonist is a technician who accepts the dangerous but extremely lucrative assignment of figuring out what’s going on. Not only does he know as much about the technology as any human being can, he’s another loner, expected to vanish when he goes inside the machine.

^^^ http://galacticjourney.org/tag/frederik-pohl/

Comment: Thank you.  I can't say for sure that's not it, but it's not ringing a bell - I don't remember people disappearing unexpectedly, and it wasn't a Mars/Earth type story, it was wider than that I think.

Comment: Any other hints? It could be beam color, field form, some countable features, just like "it took him 5 years for the transfer"

Comment: One more question: is it our days (some 20XX) or a very distant future ?

Comment: There wasn't a beam as such, it was (and I'm not sure this was explicitly stated in the book) as if the "collection" sweep from the system idled around the system checking for travellers waiting for collection but that this wasn't how it was "supposed" to be; the humans hypothesised there should be a way to be collected immediately but they didn't know how to make this happen and that led to some people waiting years for collection from less used platforms on occasion, though well used ones were serviced quickly

Comment: And again, I'm sorry, I don't clearly recall when it was set but I think further in the future because we've spread out to multiple worlds.

Comment: Were there alive aliens mentioned or they were already extinct ?

Comment: They were absent, from what I remember

Comment: Are there many teleportation devices on this kind, in different worlds ? And are they bi-directional, or just some kind of one-way portal ?

Comment: You got in to the device at one side and picked a destination, so it was one way in that sense, but you could do the reverse too and travel to any destination so effectively you could come back to where you were